# How to hide a contact from in joomla1.5

Tags: php, forms, joomla1.5, contacts

I want hide a contact form after sent msg. Only show msg successfully.[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways as far as I can see:

1. Try to find a contact module and deactivate it.
2. If that doesn't work, do a search on a word from the contact you're trying to hide, find the file it's in and modify it. You can use the windows search but you'd have to copy the all the files locally.

Answer (score 0):

Use this component. 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms/9743

I use it all the time. It has lot of features and it is free. For your problem are this features:
* Configurable page header, page text, and page image.
* Option to redirect to a link after sending a message.
And best of all: full pdf user guide.